# Paypal REST API: add a payment experience to a billing agreement

Tags: paypal

If you want to customise your store when using the payment endpoint, that's fine, you can create a payment experience and then pass the payment_experience_id to the payment endpoint.

But what if you're using the billing agreement endpoint? I notice there's no payment_experience_id field, so how do you customise the store? Can't find anything about this in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

In the PayPal standard & express payment payment reference docs, e.g.:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

... see the fields PAGESTYLE for the direct equivalent of the REST payment experience (a group of setting that you set up at an account level and apply to the payment experience as a set), or the fields HRDIMG, PAGEFLOWCOLOR, CARTBORDERCOLOR, LOGOIMG, and BRANDNAME fto override any single piece of the experince for a particular payment.

Comment: I think that's for the classic API. The billing agreement endpoint is part of the REST API.

Comment: You are correct; my answer is for the classic/EC produts. My apologies, I thought you were referring to the classic/express checkout reference transaction product. I do not know the answer to your question for the RESTful APIs.